# soql queries for junction object

Tags: force.com

[image: schema]
i have these three object as "account and client Link__c" is a junction object.
now i have to find details of Client__c where i have records of account.customerid__c.
query i have written is:

```
clientLst=[select Name from Client__c where id IN:(select User__c from Accounts_Users_Link__c where Account__r.CustomerId__c=:currentSiteCust)];
```

where " Accounts_Users_Link__r "is child relation ship name
I am getting error

> unexpected token 'select'

Comment: Is this SOQL query inside apex class/apex trigger or you executing this in Query editor of Developer Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a colon before your inner join.

Incorrect:

```
SELECT Id FROM MyObject WHERE Id IN :(/*sub-select*/)
```

Correct:

```
SELECT Id FROM MyObject WHERE Id IN (/*sub-select*/)
```